# Phrase for describing someone who ended up buying something much more expensive than what was originally needed

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, proverb-requests

Is there any popular phrase *(proverb/idiom/slang)* for describing someone who ended up buying something much more expensive than what was originally needed?

Somewhat like:

> Person A needs a bike, instead he/she paid for a Mercedes.

Ideally, whether the person succumbs to sales pitch or to his/her own greed isn't the point the phrase alludes to.

Comment: If the implication is specifically that the seller "fleeced" a naive buyer, it's more of an idiom than a proverb, but you might say "They saw you coming a mile away."

Comment: 'They _bought the shop_' has on occasion been used to describe an over-enthusiastic enterprise, but I can't find a supporting reference.

Comment: @AndyBonner, prefer no implications. Question is updated.

Comment: The sales technique is called upselling: *The slick salespeople upsold me a Mercedes*.

Comment: You say that someone has bought something with **"all the bells and whistles"** if they've added on every possible optional feature or cosmetic improvement.

Comment: @CanadianYankee, yeah, that's the closest one I can think. But I prefer something more drastic. A Mercedes is by no means a bike with all the bells and whistles.

Comment: _Bait and Switch_ is the name for the marketing strategy. _Upselling_ is just euphemism.

Comment: The essence of upselling is along the lines of "Slick Sam [the salesman] got them to spring for the extended warranty and the rust-resistant chassis spray." The implication is "They paid for a bunch of worthless or near-worthless add-ons that jacked the price up significantly."

Comment: I guess *I liked it so much I bought the company* isn't quite the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

**A fool and his money are soon parted**

> (Idiom) Used to say that a foolish person spends money too quickly on
> unimportant things [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20fool%20and%20his%20money%20are%20soon%20parted)

> This phrase is typically used to describe someone who loses their
> money quickly, either by being tricked or spending it wastefully.
> [knowyourphrase.com](https://knowyourphrase.com/a-fool-and-his-money-soon-parted)

> (Idiom) Said to mean that it is easy to persuade someone who is not sensible
> to spend their money on worthless things [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/a-fool-and-his-money-are-soon-parted)

> 'A fool and his money are soon parted' is quite an early proverb in
> the English language and, as such, might be thought to contain the
> wisdom of the ancients.
>
> The notion was known by the late 16th century, when it was
> expressed in rhyme by Thomas Tusser in *Five Hundred Pointes of Good
> Husbandrie*, 1573:
>
> > A foole & his money,
> > be soone at debate:
> > which after with sorow,
> > repents him to late.
>
> The precise wording of the expression comes just a little later, in
> Dr. John Bridges' *Defence of the Government of the Church of England*,
> 1587:
>
> > If they pay a penie or two pence more for the reddinesse of them...
> > let them looke to that, a foole and his money is soone parted.
>
> [phrases.org.uk](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/a-fool-and-his-money-are-soon-parted.html)

Comment: Thanks but it is more about wealth management than oversold.

Answer (score 0):

Their only customers are people ***with more money than sense***.

Answer (score 0):

The idiom ***to pay through the nose*** gets close. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-pay-through-the-nose) says

> If you say that you ***paid through the nose*** for something, you are emphasizing that you had to pay what you consider too high a price for it.

[FreeDict](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pay+through+the+nose) quotes *Farlex Dictionary of Idioms* and defines the idiom as meaning:

> To pay an exorbitant amount of money (for something), especially more than is reasonable.

Note that the idiom is labelled as informal.

Otherwise you can just use ***[pay a fortune for](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fortune)*** followed by a word conveying the notion of insignificant value (like ***a trifle*** for example).

Answer (score 0):

From the point of view of the person who intended to buy a bicycle but wound up buying a Mercedes Benz, there is an expression or idiom that might summarize the person's attitude regarding the purchase:

> "In for a penny, in for a pound."

His or her thinking might be along the lines of "Well, I've been willing to part with 100 dollars for a bicycle, I may as well part with 100,000 dollars for a Mercedes."

From [here](https://www.theidioms.com/in-for-a-penny-in-for-a-pound/):

> To be steadfastly dedicated to a particular course of action despite
> the fact that it is undoubtedly expensive and time-consuming.

The car buyer above is dedicated to the course of action of buying a vehicle. Despite the expense of spending a thousand times more for a Mercedes than a bicycle, the buyer channels their original and intended course of action into the buying of a car.

The same could be said of the smitten boyfriend who goes to a jewelry store to buy a charm bracelet for his latest flame. Intending to buy a 50-dollar charm bracelet, he ends up buying a finely filagreed, 18 karat gold bangle for $1000.

I could multiply examples, but won't.